# How to put a container inside a container with the borders overlaying exactly?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, containers

[How it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNgms.png)

I would like to create a caontainer that have another container inside it at the bottom.
Beacuase I am using borders in both of them I can see that they are not overlaying. That looks like this:

Is there a way to make it look like in the first picture?

[How it actually looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rf6oV.png)

My current code is looking like this:

```
                    Container(
                      height: 364.h,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        border: Border.all(
                          width: 5.r,
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Expanded(
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                          child: Container(
                            height: 50.h,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              border: Border.all(
                                width: 5.r,                            
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

Comment: use `DecoratedBox` instead outer `Container` - the docs say: *"A widget that paints a Decoration either before or after its child paints.

Container insets its child by the widths of the borders; this widget does not."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Stack** and use **alignment** to align its children at the bottom.

```
 Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  children: [
    Container(
      height: 364.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        border: Border.all(
          width: 5.0,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
        height: 50.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          border: Border.all(
            width: 5.0,
          ),
        ),
      )
  ],
);
```